# Issue starting a demon process at startup in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, scripts, startup, upstart

I tried Starting Deamon process. I am trying to run this command during startup to start  DTN2 deamon using command `dtnd -c DTN2/dtn/dtn.conf -o DTN2/dtn/log -d` in ubuntu 14.04

I made this as a shell script in one location in my computer and added it in `rc.local` e.g `sh '/pathtoscript/script.sh'`. It works when i use `sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start`. However it is not starting after the restart. How can i make sure this runs? Would creating a script using `init.d` or adding an Upstart job would be better way for running the deamon on startup for ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Yes, an init.d script would be better

Comment: Thanks ...Sorry, I am new to this Can i ask how can i use that ..As far as i kno i need to Create new script in init.d and giving path to the script which has the follwing command  dtnd -c DTN2/dtn/dtn.conf -o DTN2/dtn/log -d..making the scripts executable and configuring init.d system to run this at startup using update-rc.d script defaults...Is there any other thing i should know to start deamon using init.d....I guess i had tried this once but did not work..Did I miss anything?

Comment: See this: https://gist.github.com/naholyr/4275302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### And now, the Ubuntu answer.

You are using Ubuntu Linux. You already have either upstart or systemd (the former in this particular case). *Do not begin by writing System 5 `rc` scripts.*

`/etc/rc.local` is a double backwards compatibility mechanism, because it is a backwards compatibility mechanism for a mechanism that was itself a compatibility mechanism in System 5 `rc`. And as shown by the mess that https://askubuntu.com/a/618138/43344 addresses, using `/etc/rc.local` can go horribly wrong.  *Do not begin by using `rc.local`.*

#### upstart and version 14

So write an upstart job file.

It would look something like this:

```
# /etc/init/dtnd.conf

description "DTN2 daemon"

start on filesystem and static-network-up
stop on runlevel [016]

env DAEMON='/usr/sbin/dtnd'

respawn

exec /usr/sbin/dtnd -c /etc/dtn/dtn.conf -o /var/log/dtn/log
```

Adjust for your log and configuration set up; and use as an upstart job, in the usual manner, with `initctl start`, `initctl stop`, and so forth.

*Do not* use the `-d` option.  The program is *already* "daemonized" by dint of being run under a service manager.

#### systemd and version 15

So write a systemd service unit.

[The first rule for migrating to systemd](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/daemonize.html#first-rule) applies … yet again.  Someone has already done this.  For an example, see [`dtnd.service`](https://github.com/mittwinter/gentoo-overlay-ibrdtn/blob/master/net-misc/ibrdtnd/files/dtnd.service) written by a pseudonymous person in 2012.

Again: *Do not* use the `-d` option.  The program is *already* "daemonized" by dint of being run under a service manager.

Also note that you don't need the `-o` option.  Log to standard output/standard error in the ordinary way, and systemd will write it to the journal.

Use as a systemd service, in the usual manner, with `systemctl start`, `systemctl stop`, `systemctl status`, and so forth.  In particular, use `systemctl enable` to ensure that the service is auto-started at system bootstrap.